# If Move semantics(Move constructor and Move assignment operator) are not defined does compiler optimize by default?

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-construction, compiler-optimization, move-semantics

While defining class if we forget to write Move constructor and Move assignment operator does compiler is smart enough to optimize and add automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe, maybe not. It's not a question of whether the compiler is smart enough, but what other special member functions you have remembered, or forgotten, to define. The exact conditions when a move constructor will be implicitly defined by the compiler are listed under *§12.8/9 [class.copy]*

> If the definition of a class `X` does not explicitly declare a move constructor, one will be implicitly declared as defaulted if and only if
>   — `X` does not have a user-declared copy constructor,
>   — `X` does not have a user-declared copy assignment operator,
>   — `X` does not have a user-declared move assignment operator, and
>   — `X` does not have a user-declared destructor.

Similarly, the conditions for implicit generation of a move assignment operator are listed under *§12.8/20*

> If the definition of a class `X` does not explicitly declare a move assignment operator, one will be implicitly declared as defaulted if and only if
>   — `X` does not have a user-declared copy constructor,
>   — `X` does not have a user-declared move constructor,
>   — `X` does not have a user-declared copy assignment operator, and
>   — `X` does not have a user-declared destructor.